# Generating random numbers around a set of coordinates without for loop

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting, numpy-random

I have a set of coordinate means (3D) and a set of standard deviations (3D) accompying them like this:

```
means = [[x1, y1, z1],
         [x2, y2, z2],
         ...
         [xn, yn, zn]]

stds = [[sx1, sy1, sz1],
        [sx2, sy2, sz2],
         ...
        [sxn, syn, szn]]
```

so the problem is N x 3

I am looking to generate 1000 coordinate sample sets (N x 3 x 1000) randomly using np.random.normal(). Currently I generate the samples using a for loop:

```
for i in range(0,1000):
  samples = np.random.normal(means, stds)
```

But I have the feeling I can lose the for loop and let numpy do it faster and in one call, anybody know how I should code that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

or alternatively use the `size` argument:

```
import numpy as np

means = [ [0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1] ]
std = [ [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1] ]

#100 samples
print(np.random.normal(means, std, size = (100, len(means), 3)))
```

Comment: Can you comment on how the size argument works exactly? Maybe I am stupid but I find the docs a bit ambiguous. Should the number of 'array samples' be the first tuple member and the array dimensions the latter two?

Comment: @TheCat yes, the number of samples is the first argument so the shape of the result will be `1000, N, 3`. Numpy can broadcast two objects against each other if one of them has one "extra dimension in front", i.e., `(2,3)` can be broadcasted against `(2,2,3)` but not against `(2,3,2)`.

Comment: one could imagine that numpy generates 1000 times an object of shape `(N,3)` and then appends them together thus the resulting shape is `(1000,N,3)`...

Answer (score 0):

You can repeat your `means` and `stds` arrays 1000 times, and then call `np.random.normal()` once.

```
means = [[0, 0, 0],
         [1, 1, 1]]

stds = [[1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2]]

means = numpy.array(means) * numpy.ones(1000)[:, None, None]
stds = numpy.array(stds) * numpy.ones(1000)[:, None, None]

samples = numpy.random.normal(means, stds)
```